# How to refactor, simplify this rspec code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing these specs testing different parameters that arrived on a controller. There are some typo variations that I detect to set the gender, and based on that I update the user as male or female, but I see its look very repetitive.

Since the parameter actually happens after every each, I'm not seeing how can I simplify this. Any idea how can I simplify this code?

```
  describe "GET #create" do
    it { get :create; expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }

    context "Signup Step #1" do 
      before(:each) do 
        @user = build(:user)
      end

      context "Male" do 
        context "HOMBRE" do 
          before { get :create, full_message: "hombre", user_name: @user.name }
          it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:male) }
          it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
          it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
        end

        context "HOMVRE" do 
          before { get :create, full_message: "homvre", user_name: @user.name }
          it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:male) }
          it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
          it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
        end
      end

      context "Female" do
        context "MUJER" do
          before { get :create, full_message: "mujer", user_name: @user.name }
          it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:female) }
          it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
          it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
        end

        context "MUGER" do
          before { get :create, full_message: "muger", user_name: @user.name }
          it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:female) }
          it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
          it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
        end        
      end

    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your team's tolerance for example duplication in tests, but I've used `subject` with `let`s to reduce some of the parameter duplication.

```
describe "GET #create" do
  subject { get :create, params }

  context 'with no params' do
    let(:params) { {} }
    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }
  end

  context "Signup Step #1" do
    let(:user) { build(:user) }
    let(:user_name) { user.name }

    context "Male" do
      let(:params) { {full_message: full_message, user_name: user_name} }
      context "HOMBRE" do
        let(:full_message) { "hombre" }
        it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:male) }
        it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
        it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
      end

      context "HOMVRE" do 
        let(:full_message) { "homvre" }
        it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:male) }
        it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
        it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
      end
    end

    context "Female" do
      context "MUJER" do
        let(:full_message) { "mujer" }
        it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:female) }
        it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
        it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
      end

      context "MUGER" do
        let(:full_message) { "muger" }
        it { expect(User.last.gender).to eq(:female) }
        it { expect(response.body).to have_text("returned text okay") }
        it { expect(User.last.messages.count).to eq(3) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You could refactor out some of the expectations using Rspec's [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), but I would recommend leaving them duplicated. It will be far easier to grok for other engineers on your team and much easier to change if/when you need different behavior.